# What does "Interested in this domain?" site mean?

Tags: domains

I found a good domain but it was taken, I wrote that domain in Google search bar and this came up:

[image]

I clicked on it and this appeared:

[image]

What does this mean?

Edit: this isn't specific to one site, I have seen it in other sites

Comment: Click on it and see

Comment: ok, edited the question

Comment: @QatadaAl-Mubarak It looks like the owner put that up in case people want to contact him about buying the domain from him.